# iOS Make Navigation Bar transparent, while at the same time, preventing view to slide under Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

My problem is, when I set the navBar to transparent with this code:

```
 [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

.. the navigationbar hides the top of the viewcontroller's view:

I tried to prevent this with:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

... but then, the navbar is not transparent anymore.

How can I achieve both?

Comment: you can try  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    }

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it still slips under the navbar and is stuck at the top.

Comment: Go to storyBoard and select the controller and on right side find "Under the Top Bars" and uncheck it.

Comment: So, if the navbar is transparent and your controller's view doesn't extend behind it, what would you expect to see (behind) your transparent bar?...

Comment: @Alladinian, There is a background image on the top, if the viewcontroller is called, only half of the image is shown, the other half is "over the top". If I scroll down and up again, it (weirdly) appears in the adequate position.
Only upon calling the VC the first time, only half of the image is shown (if "self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;" is not set, that is).

Comment: @aBilal17 I work with a XIB file, am not able to find that option :/

Comment: @BesfortAbazi this "Under the Top Bars" is available in xib file as well. check this image. https://ibb.co/iwcw8d